# Ignore color escapes in Awk

Tags: bash, awk

I'd like to use `awk` to parse an output containing color escape codes.
But awk fails to interpret colored number as numbers:

```
echo "[1,2,3]" | jq -C '.[]' | awk '{print $1," -> ",int($1)}'

1  ->  0
2  ->  0
3  ->  0
```

As you can see the color codes (inserted by `jq -C`) prevent the string from parsing as an integer.
Is there a way to remove/ignore the escape color code from the input ?
Bonus point if the solution doesn't use regexes.

Comment: The easiest solution is to postprocess the `jq` command with `sed "s,\x1B\[[0-9;]*[a-zA-Z],,g"` and then use `awk`. You can also do this in `awk` with `gsub`

Comment: In Debian there is package `colorized-logs` whis has tool `ansi2txt` which seems to do the job. EDIT: Apparently it's mentioned in the attached link with a fix to bold problem.